# Screenshot of running Google Chrome browser in OS X from Python

Tags: python, macos, screenshot

When I run Selenium-style integration tests with Google Chrome on OS X from a Python script, I'd like to take screenshots at each step. I'd like to just capture the Google Chrome window, not the whole desktop. Is there any way to do a screen grab of a currently running Google Chrome window in OS X from a Python script?

Comment: Seems like you could use `subprocess` to call an apple script that runs the Grab app, but there's probably a much more elegant way that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that selenium has a [get_screenshot_as_file](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#taking-a-screenshot) method that works with OS X and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I've not done it from OS X on Chrome, but does something like this not work:

```
browser.open("/page-to-capture")
png = browser.capture_screenshot_to_string()
with open("screenshot.png", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(png.decode('base64'))
```

Certainly it has worked for me in the past using selenium on linux with firefox.

Comment: There appears to be a get_screenshot_as_file method that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the ["`screencapture`" command line](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html) tool under MacOS.  Can you call that from your Python script?

One of the options is "`-w`", which is "window selection mode".  I'm not certain if this will work from within a script (i.e. does it require user interaction?), but if that doesn't work you could also try "`-m`", which is the "only capture main monitor" option.

Comment: I can, but the problem is that I would need to pass it the windowid, and I don't know how to retrieve it for Google Chrome, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73994/how-do-i-find-the-windowid-of-google-chrome-to-pass-to-screencapture-l

Comment: Not Applescriptable? Ewwww. You may need to write some kind of Javascript extension for Google chrome to output the window ID or make it available via some other semi-clunky way.